# Simple Java code, having trouble creating a C++ equivalent (private static members and public accessor methods)

Tags: java, c++, static, pass-by-reference

I'm a Java developer with 7 years of experience but I'm almost entirely new to C++. This isn't homework or even for real paid work. I'm just delving into C++ and having trouble emulating this one particular pattern that I use frequently in Java.

Basically (in Java):

```
    public class ExampleManager
    { 
       private static Example _example;

       public static Example getExample()
       { 
          return _example;
       }

       public static void setExample(Example example)
       {
          _example = example;
       }
    }
```

I've so far tried about four variants with what I've learned about C++. I found that passing  'example' with the same syntax gets me a copy of 'example' stored in the class. I understand most of the logic behind pointers, just not a lot of the specifics. This example would go a long way to help me with that.

If someone could give me equivalent C++ code to this so that I can break it down line by line and step through it, I would appreciate it very much.

I don't use this pattern as is in Java, but its the bones of the pattern I use to maintain thread safe access to single instance members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basically equivalent code in C++ would be this:

```
class ExampleManager
{ 
private:
   static std::shared_ptr<Example> _example;

public:
   static std::shared_ptr<Example> getExample()
   { 
      return _example;
   }

   static void setExample(std::shared_ptr<Example> example)
   {
      _example = example;
   }
};
```

It makes use of the `std::shared_ptr` class, which does most of the memory handling stuff for you (you only have to `new` objects, basically just like in Java).

We do not use "raw" pointers (i.e. `Example *`) here; usage of "raw" pointers is usually frowned upon (unless you're working in an environment with limited resoures, or close to hardware), since it gains you little in terms of performance but can lead to ugly problems (memory leaks, double deletions, ...) if not considered carefully.

Please note that the `shared_ptr` used above is only part of the standard since C++11. Most halfway recent compilers will already accept its usage like shown above; for some a bit older ones you might have to do special things:

- e.g. for g++ <= 4.6, add `-std=c++0x` to compilation command line
- for some you might have to use `std::tr1::shared_ptr`
- if both of the above options fail, you can use [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) from the boost libraries.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Apparently I need to wait 15 minutes to be able to accept it. :-)

I'll look into the specifics of shared_ptr now too. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @juanchopanza I did notice the accessibility modifiers were Java style. But that's trivial.

Comment: @ScottDrew right. But note that the `public` class thing is a concept that doesn't really exist in C++.

Comment: That comes under accessibility modifiers doesn't it? Thanks for the input, though I gleamed what I needed to from the original answer. :-)